# How to display milliseconds instead of seconds using timer_stop function?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to display milliseconds instead of seconds using [timer_stop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop) wordpress function.
Currently I have

```
$sbp_speed = timer_stop(0,2);
```

That display the time like `1.56` s and I need to display the time like `455.1 ms`

Thank you!

Comment: This is a general/generic PHP question not a WordPress question, I recommend instead you ask on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just multiply it by 1000:

```
$sbp_speed = 1000 * ( float ) timer_stop( 0, 4 );
```

Comment: @Tom J Nowell as far I know [timer_stop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop) is a WordPress function. Am I missing something? Nevermind...

Comment: timer_stop can be returned with comma, so replace is needed: `$total_time = 1000 * ( float ) str_replace(',', '.', timer_stop( 0, 6 ));`